# Microsoft SSMS: logs of previous database checks

Tags: sql-server

About a year ago I have fixed some SQL Server databases for one of our clients. 
Now he asks if there is more information about the repairs done to the databases.

I have tried googling for SMSS logs but cannot seem to find anything worthwhile.

Question: are there any logs about the previous checks and restorations of databases (using CHECKDB)?

I have tried `Database > Reports > Standard Reports > Database Consistency History` yet it shows nothing.

Going to `Management > SQL Server Logs` I can see archives from 3 months ago but not earlier.

Any possibilities for me to find earlier logs?

Comment: I would very much doubt that you'll have any logs left from 1 year ago on your instance. That would not be default behaviour, unless the server hadn't been shut down in the last 12 months (and that's a very different concern if so). If you didn't log or record the information then, you won't be able to get it now.

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool. It doesn't keep any logs itself. What you see comes from the server itself. The logs you see are the maintenance logs stored in the server itself, based on the data pulled by querying the server's DMVs

Comment: Live and learn. If you repair data (as in, using `DBCC CHECKDB` to recover from corruption) take a backup before and after the operation, both so you can make an actual comparison and to retain access to any data `CHECKDB` may have actually destroyed in its efforts to restore consistency. Trying to figure out what happened a year later would be hard even if you had a complete log file.

Comment: @JeroenMostert of course, the backups were made, I tried attaching them to my own server and those that could not be attached were corrupted for sure, however, I remember that I could attach more databases that I repaired later and then gave it back. Furthermore, another company tried to attach the backups and they somehow repaired the backups, now I cannot see what backups were corrupted. Almost everything seems ok :D Anyway, Thanks for the info guys.